# "[...] hasn't worked for me as much as I would like it to has": is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, semantics

Is the following sentence grammatically and semantically correct? If not, what would be its alternatives?

> [...] but unfortunately, that principle hasn't worked for me as much as I would like it to has.

I was trying to say that there is a method/principle such that upon being followed, it solves/prevents certain problems form occurring. But that method hasn't work for me as I was expecting it to do.

Comment: *...as much as I would like it **to have** [worked for me]*. The auxiliary ***have*** is an infinitive form, as in *I would like **to know** the answer.*

Comment: I'm not sure, @FumbleFingers: Would you consider "...as much as I'd have liked" - which is what *I* say - to be wrong? Isn't that what people usually say?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Sure, that's fine. But it's really neither here nor there whether you cast the *mandatory* initial verb as a Perfect form *(...as much as **I would like / I would have liked / I'd have liked / I'd've liked**)*. The issue here is whether or not to "delete" the "predictably repeated" element ***...to have worked for me*** - and if so, ***how much***. That, and the fact that if you ***do*** repeat the auxiliary ***have*** here, it must be the infinitive (not ***has***).

Comment: ...arguably in *some* contexts, there could be a nuance of difference between *I didn't get as much as I expected* and the "Conditional Perfect" version *(...as much as I **would have** expected)* - where the Perfect version *might* suggest that I hadn't given the matter any thought until after I received what struck me immediately as *less that I would have expected **if** I had thought about it*. But mostly I think that's a pedantic distinction that primarily reflects differences in possible vocabulary and syntax, rather than real-world differences that need to be differentiated.

Comment: Good points. Thank you. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verbal construction you are using is "would like sth to + inf without to".

- I would like my skirt **to be** shorter.
- I would like the car **to go** fast.
- I would like the cake **to have** a cherry on top.
- I would like it **to have** worked for me too, but it didn't.

You can see that in the four sentences above a conjugated form would not do. So, you must use the infinitive in the sentence you examine.

- but unfortunately, that principle hasn't worked for me as much as I would like it to have worked.

However, in this grammatical context you normally use a so called pro-form for "to have worked" (to). ([Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb))

- but unfortunately, that principle hasn't worked for me as much as I would like it to.